# Meteor 301 redirect nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, http-status-code-301

How do I redirect www.site.com to site.com with 301 in meteorjs.

I normally use express but we don't have that in `meteor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in packages/accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_server.js you'll find an example of how make the server listen on HTTP:

```
// Listen to incoming OAuth http requests
__meteor_bootstrap__.app
  .use(connect.query())
  .use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Need to create a Fiber since we're using synchronous http
    // calls and nothing else is wrapping this in a fiber
    // automatically
    Fiber(function () {
      Accounts.oauth._middleware(req, res, next);
    }).run();
  });
```

Instead of spawing a Fiber and calling into the OAuth middleware logic, you can check `req.url` and either set HTTP headers with `res.writeHead` and call `res.end()`, or continue into the usual Meteor stack with `next()`.

Comment: Don't want to create an argument here, but my suggestion of editing this post and modifying res.next() to next() still appears correct, even though it was rejected.

Comment: Quite right.  Don't know why it was rejected.  I just made the change.

Comment: Is this advice still correct after the introduction of websockets? I notice force-ssl doesn't use this approach. `packages/force-ssl/force_ssl_server.js`